# Good resources for turning Emacs into a LaTeX IDE?

Tags: latex, auctex, tex

I am learning Emacs thanks to awesome resources like [this](https://github.com/nobiot/Zero-to-Emacs-and-Org-roam) or [this](https://github.com/rougier/emacs-gtd). However, I can't find a good tutorial for setting up AucTeX in order to turn Emacs into a LaTeX IDE. I am trying to set it up with the official user guide, but I find it hard to follow.

Any good resource?

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50827/a-simpletons-guide-to-tex-workflow-with-emacs It's a bit old, though.

Comment: For a more IDE-like experience, you can consider using a language server on top of AucTeX. There is https://github.com/astoff/digestif and https://github.com/latex-lsp/texlab

Comment: There's LSP integration with TeXlab as @Augusto said, you can find it [here](https://texlab.netlify.app/) and the install [here](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-latex/)

Comment: The question encourages opinion-based answers. As such, it isn't a good fit for StackExchange. Questions here should typically be concrete how-to questions or questions about understanding something specific.